# which is the easyer way :install ubuntu first and then windows 7 , or the other way around?

Tags: java, windows-7, ubuntu

hy , i 'm currently formating my laptop and i ' thinking of installing ubuntu and window7 .I know there are some problems with booting both .My question is which is the easy-er way :install ubuntu first and then windows 7 , or the other way around?

Comment: I want to say Ubuntu  , but its not suitable here :)

Comment: Do windows first.  Then ubuntu.  That's how I do it.  Ubuntu will overwrite the bootloader to the grub bootloader and allow you to boot into both.

Comment: It seems like you need tie down your requirements before asking this kind of question, then to ask it somewhere else.

Comment: Of course it is Ubuntu! Then install VirtualBox and install Windows XP in it. That's how I do it and I'm VERY satisfied! This way I can run Linux and Windows at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using something like virtualbox to run virtual machines, then you can have a virtual linux development machine, and a virtual windows development machine, and your host system can be whatever you want, and optionally can be clean of any development related programs.